# I didnt understood the flow of programme

Tags: c, linux, device, drivers

I have Ethernet Device driver source file. I didnt understood the flow of programme. I know module_init & module_exit. Using module_init, init funciton is initializing after no function is calling anywhere....

```
static int __init
jme_init_module(void)
{
    pr_info("JMicron JMC2XX ethernet driver version %s\n", DRV_VERSION);
return pci_register_driver(&jme_driver);
}

static void __exit
jme_cleanup_module(void)
{
    pci_unregister_driver(&jme_driver);
}

module_init(jme_init_module);
module_exit(jme_cleanup_module);
```

Comment: How does one flag question as "OP needs to study up first" ?

Comment: Guys let me know the answer. Thanks in advance. and I dont how to add the source code. It is nearly 3000 lines

Comment: Alright, drivers don't flow. Drivers work as callbacks to events, there is somewhere struct with callbacks in your source code. Also, drivers are  nearly the hardest kind of programming and since it doesn't exactly seem you realize that I would recommend the book 'Linux device drivers'. there is a skeleton project you can learn a lot from that.

Comment: Basically in init you are initializing the driver and in exit you are cleaning up. As said by @Pyjong drivers are a bit tricky. They are used to interact with hardware so they respond to interrupts. There are ISRs written in your driver for various interrupts on various ports/pins that you have configured and ISR response to those interrupts. Have allok at the LDD , how to write a char driver. This will make you understand how drivers work. Its a simple driver to learn the behavior . All other driver are also wrtten in almost same manner but yes the implementation is hardware specific.